# How to make two counters buttons independent of each other in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I was struggling in making 'like' buttons which on clicking increases or decreases the count whenever clicked and the problem I am facing is ,the interference of one button on other buttons.Here is my html code for one button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default buttonattr"style="font-family:Pangolin"   onclick="myhit1(\''+this["post"]+'\',\''+this["id"]+'\',\''+this["love"]+'\');myclick()">
     <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg active1"></span> Love
</button>;
```

where `myhit()` and `myclick()`are  javascript functions, called on clicking this button . Here is my javascript functions:

```
var toAdd=1;var newValue=0;
 var overall=1;var pvalue=0;
 function myhit(post,id,love){

 oldValue=parseInt(love);



 if(toAdd>0){

 newValue=oldValue+toAdd;
 }
 else{

 newValue= overall + toAdd;
 }
 pvalue=pvalue+toAdd;
 toAdd*=-1;
 overall=newValue;


 $.post('porthome4_.php',{post1:post,id1:id,love:newValue,plove:pvalue},function(info){});

 }
```

I have made more 'like' buttons for each post. The problem is for eg. if I click on one button and the counter is increased from 0->1 state ,but if click on another button its state change is absurd , and I know is the reason is `toAdd` variable state change from +1 to -1 because its state change for every click on  button ,,it  would have worked fine if there would have been only 1 button but 
 for multiple buttons this wont work...Can someone suggest me better way to tackle this or a change in my function code would be much more appreciated . Would be glad if someone helps.Thank u

Comment: One option would be to not use global variables, but use `$(this).data("overall")` - thus the value is stored on the button itself and is therefore separate from other buttons' values.

Comment: hmm,seems good ,let me try and get back to u @freedomn-m but wait toAdd still  changes it state so in one button it would add and if I go to another button it would substract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-default buttonattr"style="font-family:Pangolin" data-state="1" onclick="myhit1(\''+this["post"]+'\',\''+this["id"]+'\',\''+this["love"]+'\');myclick()">
    <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart fa-lg active1"></span> Love
</button>

var newValue=0;
var overall=1;
var pvalue=0;

function myhit(post,id,love)
{
    oldValue = parseInt(love);
    var toAdd = parseInt($(this).attr("data-state"));
    if(toAdd>0)
    {
        newValue=oldValue+toAdd;
    }
    else
    {
        newValue= overall + toAdd;
    }
    pvalue=pvalue+toAdd;
    toAdd*=-1;
    overall=newValue;

    $(this).attr("data-state",toAdd);

    $.post('porthome4_.php',{post1:post,id1:id,love:newValue,plove:pvalue},function(info){});
}
```

Comment: not working parseInt($(this).attr("data-state")) says its not a number,,,whyyy?

Answer (score 1):

You can used separate state variable for each button. Set `data-state` attribute to button and after that you can used this attribute to function `$(this).data("data-state");` you can get and set this value each time whne button click.

Comment: Can u give code,how to implement data-state in my html and jquery ,I dont know abt it so,I googled it but couldn't find something accurate ,,Can u help me with this ,plz

Comment: <button class="btn btn-default" data-state="1">

    ...

    function myhit(post,id,love){

    ...

    var toAdd = $(this).data("state");

    ...

    toAdd*=-1;
    $(this).attr("data-state", -1);

    ...

    }

Comment: Thank u Paresh bhaiya,

Comment: not working  **parseInt($(this).attr("data-state"))** says its not a number,,,whyyy?

Comment: I think you set "-1" after state change so it's not take as number, you can get value without parseInt() function and try

Comment: I think we need to pass this as parameter in  `myhit1()` function to tell that this is the button I am referring to